# Compile error while building g2o for Kinetic RGBDSLAM

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I follow the procedure of https://github.com/felixendres/g2o, to build g2o,

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

I got the following compile error,

```
/home/user/g2o/g2o-master/g2o/types/slam2d/edge_se2_pointxy_bearing.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void g2o::EdgeSE2PointXYBearing::initialEstimate(const VertexSet&, g2o::OptimizableGraph::Vertex*)’:
/home/user/g2o/g2o-master/g2o/types/slam2d/edge_se2_pointxy_bearing.cpp:51:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘g2o::SE2::setRotation(Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::Scalar)’
     t.setRotation(t.rotation().angle()+_measurement);
                                                    ^
In file included from /home/user/g2o/g2o-master/g2o/types/slam2d/vertex_se2.h:33:0,
                 from /home/user/g2o/g2o-master/g2o/types/slam2d/edge_se2_pointxy_bearing.h:31,
                 from /home/user/g2o/g2o-master/g2o/types/slam2d/edge_se2_pointxy_bearing.cpp:27:
/home/user/g2o/g2o-master/g2o/types/slam2d/se2.h:59:12: note: candidate: void g2o::SE2::setRotation(const Rotation2Dd&)
       void setRotation(const Eigen::Rotation2Dd& R_) {_R=R_;}
            ^
/home/user/g2o/g2o-master/g2o/types/slam2d/se2.h:59:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Eigen::Rotation2D<double>::Scalar {aka double}’ to ‘const Rotation2Dd& {aka const Eigen::Rotation2D<double>&}’
g2o/types/slam2d/CMakeFiles/types_slam2d.dir/build.make:206: recipe for target 'g2o/types/slam2d/CMakeFiles/types_slam2d.dir/edge_se2_pointxy_bearing.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [g2o/types/slam2d/CMakeFiles/types_slam2d.dir/edge_se2_pointxy_bearing.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1016: recipe for target 'g2o/types/slam2d/CMakeFiles/types_slam2d.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [g2o/types/slam2d/CMakeFiles/types_slam2d.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the root cause of it and how can I solve it? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250909/compile-error-while-building-g2o-for-kinetic-rgbdslam/) by [kywang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28915/kywang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-12-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-30**:
Please just accept your own answer instead of closing the question. Accepted answers mark a question as answered, which has higher visibility than a closed question.

Thanks.

**Comment by [Yahahaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29991/yahahaa/) on 2017-04-11**:
I am having the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the late reply.
I followed the following script procedure to set up and build the software, the errors were gone, though I did not dig out the root cause.
The script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/kinetic/install.sh ,
from here: https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2 .
Please try it, and thanks for anyone's help about this question.

---

Originally posted by [kywang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28915/kywang/) with karma: 46 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2017-03-05**:
Can you detail your solution please?i have just faced same problem.

**Comment by [jylee0121](https://answers.ros.org/users/32226/jylee0121/) on 2017-10-12**:
install.sh uses branch "c++03", not "master" when it clones g2o git repository . The author of rgbdslam, Felix  Endes  modified some configuration code.